# What will be the distribution of the difference of the longest and shortest waiting time?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

John would like to eat at one of the fast food restaurants around him. There are $n$ fast food restaurants around him, and the the waiting time at the $i$-th has exponential distribution: $p(T_i) \sim \exp(λ_i)$. What will be the distribution of the difference of the longest and shortest waiting time, if $λ_i=λ>0 ∀i$?
I think it will also be an exponential distribution, because we are just taking the difference of 2 exponential distribution. Is this answer good? Or should I / Can I calculate something else too?

Comment: It might well be an exponential distribution, but your reasoning about it being such because it is "the difference of 2 exponential distributions" is not valid.

Comment: @MarkFischler How should I argue then?

Comment: Using memorylessness and conditional distributions, I think this problem can be reduced to understanding the distribution of $\max_i T_i$, where the $T_i$ are a finite family of independent exponential variables. But I don't think that distribution has any kind of nice expression.

Answer (score 1):

Let's find the distribution of the longest waiting time $X_L$:

$$f_i(x) = \lambda_i e^{-\lambda_i x}$$

$$P(x_i > X) = 1-F_i(X) =  e^{-\lambda_i X}$$

$$1- F_L(X) \equiv P (\forall i \,: \,x_i>X) = \prod_i e^{-\lambda_i X} = e^{-\sum_i \lambda_i X}$$
$$F_L(X) = 1-e^{-\sum_i \lambda_i X}$$
So the desired distribution is
$$
f_L(X) = \frac{d}{dX}F_L(X) = \sum_i \lambda_i e^{-\sum_i \lambda_i X}
$$
So the distribution of the longest waiting time is indeed exponential, with $\lambda$ being the sum of the individual $\lambda_i$s.

The distribution of the shortest waiting time $F_S(X)$ is a bit tougher to calculate:
$$P(x_i < X) = F_i(X) = 1-e^{-\lambda_i x}$$

$$
F_S(X) \equiv P (\forall i \,: \,x_i<X) = \prod_i \left( 1-e^{-\lambda_i X}\right)
$$
$$
f_S(X) = \frac{d}{dX}(F_S(X)) = \sum_i \frac{\lambda_i e^{-\lambda_i X}}{\left( 1-e^{-\lambda_i X}\right) } \prod_k \left( 1-e^{-\lambda_k X}\right)
$$
That is not a very clean expression, but in fact the answer is simply not clean.

Comment: What do you denote with $F_i(X)$?

Comment: Ah, it's the cumulative density function, right?

Comment: Knowing the distribution of $X$ and $Y$ isn't enough to obtain the distribution of $X-Y$.

Comment: @JackM So the problem is not solvable?